# How to get specific terms of a polynomial function in a regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, fitting, lm, polynomial

I want to simplify data from a complex modell like:

```
fit <- lm(z ~ poly(a,4)*poly(b,5)*poly(c,6), data = somewhat)
```

As I don't know which terms of the complete formula are relevant to my z, I created a subset like this:

```
temp <- summary(fit)
d <- t(data.frame(subset(temp[["coefficients"]][,4],temp[["coefficients"]] 
[,4]<0.0001)))
```

Then I formed a variable with the colnames of d that would look like this:

```
s = "(poly(a, 4, raw = FALSE)1:poly(b, 5, raw = FALSE)3:poly(c, 6, raw = 
FALSE)6)+(poly(a, 4, raw = FALSE)4:poly(b, 5, raw = FALSE)2:poly(c, 6, raw = 
FALSE)2"
```

What I wanted to do is to set up a new fitting model

```
fit2 <- lm(z ~ s, data = somewhat)
```

But I receive the error message:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "fit2 <- lm(z ~ (poly(a, 4, raw = 
FALSE)1"
```

So obviously, the format of s is not useable as a formula. Any ideas how I could automatically cut out the irrelevant terms of the first modell? My original model has about 7000 different terms, so evaluating it manually is not an option.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, that many terms will surely be full of false positives.

Comment: What would suggest to do instead?

Comment: You could use the `step()` function to do this for you, doing it backwards or forwards or both, however this is discouraged. You should use your domain knowledge to determine which terms should be included and to what degree, but honestly if you are using polynomials of third degree or more there is something wrong with your data or your understanding, even degree two is already suspicious. If you really have that wavy data you should look into splines or GAMs, or some other model altogether. BTW is this time series data?

Comment: The data is derivated from a program that calculates machine characteristics - in dependence of ambient conditions for example. As I want to check just part of this characteristic with a huge set of those conditions I need to simplify the calculation. The original program would take far too long for this amount of sets.
So, to sum it up: I am sure that the "observations" I use are absolute useable and due to the physics behind the machine it might also be possble that there are interactions between the regressors even in a higher order.
As I actually am an engineer: What is time series data?

Comment: It is meaningless, in general, to drop lower-order terms of a polynomial: the polynomial makes sense only in the context of all of its terms up to a given order.  The strategy of fitting high-order polynomials is usually counterproductive, too.  (The only exceptions I have ever encountered are where there is a strong theoretical basis for the polynomial behavior--and for multivariate polynomials like these, that's extremely rare.)  You would be better served by explaining what your statistical objectives are, rather than trying to fix up this approach.

Comment: If you make scatterplots of each independent variable vs. the dependent variable, visual inspection may reveal those variables with strong relationships and also if any obvious data transformation (such as log) that could produce a simpler model. This is fairly quick to perform and might yield useful results.

Comment: I think the comments in aggregate are forming a good answer.  Let me add that there are methods like ridge regression, lasso, and LARS that can be useful in these cases, and are usually considered preferable to stepwise methods.  Also, using statistics like AIC, AICc, or BIC are useful to compare among potential models.  Finally, I'll link to [this slide set by Flom and Cassell](http://denversug.org/presentations/2010coday/stopsteppresntn.pdf), partially because I like the phrase "Garbage in, fake pearls out".

Comment: Before I tried the regression, I took a look on the relationship of each independent variable with the dependent. From those inspections I found the orders of the polynomials of each variable. But I am sure, that there are interactions between my parameters. What I don't know is which parameters interact and with which order this interaction can be expressed properly.
But what I assume from your answers is that I should try to simplify the model by hand to get more realistic interactions instead of trying to let an algorithm do this for me?